# Ant exec task using cURL to POST a JSON body doesn't work, identical command works manually in Windows command prompt

Tags: java, html, json, curl, ant

I'm running this task as part of a larger target in an Ant script. It executes a command in the Windows command prompt and routes the output to a text file in the temp directory. I've changed the URL argument to protect sensitive information.

```
<exec executable="cf.cmd" output="${java.io.tmpdir}/cmd_out.txt" failonerror="true" vmlauncher="false">
    <arg value="curl" />
    <arg value="POST" />
    <arg value="http://www.google.com/v2/routes" />
    <arg value="--body" />
    <arg value="&#39;{&quot;host&quot;: &quot;${old.app.name}&quot;, &quot;domain_guid&quot;: &quot;${domain.guid}&quot;, &quot;space_guid&quot;: &quot;${space.guid}&quot;}&#39;" />
</exec>
```

From Ant's verbose logs, this task produces the following command:

```
Current OS is Windows 7
[exec] Output redirected to C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Temp\cmd_out.txt
[exec] Executing 'cf' with arguments:
[exec] 'curl'
[exec] 'POST'
[exec] 'http://www.google.com/v2/routes'
[exec] '--body'
[exec] ''{"host": "foo", "domain_guid": "4cc4c9b0-5b87-40f5-8ecc-6d6347a3236d", "space_guid": "6c3338e2-422d-46c0-a901-eda41b1fd968"}''
[exec] 
[exec] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
[exec] not part of the command.
```

When run, this task produces the following output in cmd_out.txt:

```
{
  "code": 1001,
  "description": "Request invalid due to parse error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.\n                                      {host: foo, domain_guid\n                     (right here) ------^\n
  "error_code": "CF-MessageParseError
  "types": [
    "MessageParseError
    "Error"
  ],
  "backtrace": []
}
```

However, if I execute this identical command manually in the Windows command prompt:

```
cf curl POST http://www.google.com/v2/routes --body '{"host": "foo", "domain_guid": "4cc4c9b0-5b87-40f5-8ecc-6d6347a3236d", "space_guid": "6c3338e2-422d-46c0-a901-eda41b1fd968"}'
```

Then I get the correct result. No point in posting it here, but it's a success message instead of an invalid parse error message.

If I run this command in the manual Windows command prompt (notice the lack of single quotes around the JSON body), then I get the same error as the Ant script:

```
cf curl POST http://www.google.com/v2/routes --body {"host": "foo", "domain_guid": "4cc4c9b0-5b87-40f5-8ecc-6d6347a3236d", "space_guid": "6c3338e2-422d-46c0-a901-eda41b1fd968"}
```

I'm at a loss here. From what I can see, Ant is running the same command as what I am doing manually. Yet the Ant version fails, and the manual version succeeds. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the spaces were causing the problem. Changing the exec task to the following works great:

```
<exec executable="cf.cmd" output="${java.io.tmpdir}/cmd_out.txt" failonerror="true" vmlauncher="false">
    <arg value="curl" />
    <arg value="POST" />
    <arg value="http://www.google.com/v2/routes" />
    <arg value="--body" />
    <arg value="&apos;{&quot;host&quot;:&quot;${old.app.name}&quot;,&quot;domain_guid&quot;:&quot;${domain.guid}&quot;,&quot;space_guid&quot;:&quot;${space.guid}&quot;}&apos;" />
</exec>
```

Comment: I also used "&apos;" for the single quotes instead of the hex representation, but I don't think that matters.